# Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents on Unit Test

Tags: c#, excel, testing

There are a lot of posts about this, but with asp.net, I have checked them, but I couldn't find anything that worked for me.

There is a test in our application that access an excel file, like this:

```
Excel.Application _excelApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = false };

// get a new workbook
_workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
```

And it fails with the following error at the line where tries to add a new Workbook:

> Test method
>   MyNamespace.MyTestMethod
>   threw exception:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there
>   is not enough available memory or disk space.
>
> • To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no
>   longer need.
>
> • To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk
>   you are saving to.

We are closing Excel like this:

```
[TestCleanup]
public new void TestCleanup()
{
   if (_window.IsLoaded)
      _window.Close();
      // If Excel app loaded cleanup
      if (_workbook != null)
      {
         _workbook.Close(false);
         _excelApp.Quit();
      }
}
```

This error makes no sense since the disk has plenty of space. Our build "server" is running Windows 7, TFS launches the builds through the Network Service User. 
Every other test works perfectly, we are just having issues with the ones trying to use excel.

I think this is an issue of access rights, but what access could the NetworkService user be missing to make this work?

Comment: A little unrelated, but why are you accessing Excel directly in a unit test? Is it because it's an integration test and not a unit test, or because you really want to test the driver?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - Thanks for your question. I didn't create the test, it is some legacy code :( But yes, it is more of an Integration Test than a UnitTest. Change it to remove Excel and use a Proxy is a lot work I can't afford to do right now. However I am really curious as to what  should I do to make it work since in a previous server that was running with an Admin User (complex story there) it was working, so I realize it is something related with access rights.

Comment: How are you saving / closing Excel? If you pull up your Task Manager and go to Processes, do you see a bunch of Excel instances? If you don't properly close out of it in your code, it'll stay running in the background. You need to use `myWorkbook.Close()` and `myExcelApp.Quit()`

Comment: @sab669 - I updated my question with the code used to close excel. There are no excel instances hung on the Task Manager.

Comment: Have you tried turning off all the trust centre settings for Excel? They've caused us of all sorts of automation issues.  The difficulty will be turning them off for the Network Service User account I guess - is it possible to login as that user?  

If it is, you could also try building a small app that contains the same behaviour, but doesn't set Excel to hidden and then install and run that on the server?  That may show up some other Excel warning that's the true cause of the issue.

Comment: Side note: since running Office Apps in headless/server environment is not supported you will have hard time finding approaches that would work. Running under actual logged in user account may be slightly better (after interactively logging in with that account to setup whatever interactive user needs)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I had read that running Excel in a server with iis wasn't supported, I wasn't totally sure it would apply for tests like we are doing. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @tom_redox - No, I haven't. I will check it out. I will also try to see if it is possible to log with that user.